# iScroll4 doesn't work in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, slider, iscroll4

I made an app that shows lots of images. I used iscroll4 to slide them smoothly with touch (mobile) and mouse (web), but it doesn't work in IE7 or IE8. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/iscroll/ie8/iscroll/c9iX8vixgbM/OjwdKvRy1EAJ and try **Alan H** js file.

This works in IE7 also, although there is still some lack of event listener support for iscroll in IE.

You can also try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >` or you can try with `IE=EmulateIE7` in your `html head tag`. This works fine with compatibile view but has some issues in standard view.

You can check the following url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode for better understanding. Let me know if this helps.